# Can’t connect to Windows 10 via ssh neither netcat

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ssh

I have installed 'OpenSSH SSH Server' on Windows 10 machine,(and it’s running) and I'm trying to connect from Kali Linux machine but I always get "ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.181 port 22: Connection timed out"

Same thing with netcat. I go on Windows 10: ncat -nlvp 2900 and on Kali: nc 192.168.1.181 2900 and after 3-4min I get: "(UNKNOWN) [192.168.1.181] 2900 (?) : Connection timed out" I have no problem connecting from WIN10 to Kali whatsoever. I've had a success connecting to windows10 from Kali thru Ngrok, but now that doesn't work either. BTW. in 'Firewall with Advanced Security' I can see that 'OpenSSH SSH Server' is enabled and connection are allowed... I've been fighting with this for days now, I run out of ideas... What else I can do, how to make this connection work?